# Saving AND showing plots in rmd file

Tags: r, plot, save, r-markdown, show

I'm working on a rather long code using R markdown, divided into chunks. Plot appear under the appropriate chunk. I'd like to keep this behaviour, but additionally I want to save them to a specified folder. I've tried different methods listed here [How to save a plot as image on the disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk) (and elsewhere on the Internet), but nothing seems to work.
My reproducible example:

```
png('cars_plot.png')
plot(cars)
dev.off()
```

This code saves the plot, but doesn't show it (it only returns "null device 1"). I've also tried dev.print and dev.copy, with the same result.
Thank you in advance!
Clarification: I run my chunks one by one, I don't want to convert my results to pdf/html yet. So [knitr: include figures in report *and* output figures to separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files) or [change where rmarkdown saves images generated by r code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083106/change-where-rmarkdown-saves-images-generated-by-r-code) don't answer my question.

Comment: have you tried to just run the `plot(cars)` function outside your dev environment?

Comment: also this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083106/change-where-rmarkdown-saves-images-generated-by-r-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knitr: include figures in report \*and\* output figures to separate files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files)

Comment: yes, duplicate. add Use the option `self_contained: no` in your rmd header and the files will be available in a separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can always graph it twice in the same markdown chunk, like this:

```
plot(cars)

png('cars_plot.png')

plot(cars)

dev.off()
```

Comment: One may want to use either `dev.off() -> .` (`.` as kind of /dev/null variable similar to `_` in Python/Prolog) or `invisible(dev.off())` to suppress an output from the command.