# How to save a plot in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, r-markdown, save

I am currently working on a project where I need to extract pngs from a RMarkdown, i have tried to use ggsave but it returns an error about $, but i havent used them in my prompt.

I tried this for now :

```
chene_cor = cor(Chene_num)
chene_cor
sauve = corrplot(chene_cor)
ggsave(filename = "corrplotchene", plot = "sauve", device = "svg")
```

When I run this code, I get this error :

```
Error in x$theme : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any ideas on how to fix that ? If not, any other ideas to save plots in Rmd ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677965/saving-and-showing-plots-in-rmd-file>

Comment: remove quotation marks from `plot = "suave"` and try that? The complaint is that it cannot extract `$theme` from a string `"suave"`.

Comment: Do you want the plot files to be available in a separate folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `ggsave()` without the `plot` parameter. See below:

```
ggsave(filename = "corrplotchene", device = "svg")
```

`ggsave()` automatically fetches and saves the last plot.