# R Notebook/Markdown does not save chunk plots using "fig.path = " chunk option

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, chunks, rnotebook

I'm running an analysis in an R Notebook and I would like all plots created in R chunks to be saved as individual PDF files ***in addition to*** appearing in the .nb.html notebook output.

#### The problem

The problem I'm having is that, when the notebook is run, it does not save plots to the dir specified in the chunk option `fig.path = "figures/"` either when specified in the individual chunk header:

````
#```{r fig.path = "figures/"}
plot(x, y)
#```
````

or when specified with the global chunk options:

````
#```{r setup}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figures/")
#```

#```{r}
plot(x, y)
#```
````

In fact, there is no dir named `*figures/` ***at all, anywhere***. not in the project root directory nor in the dir where the .Rmd script is located. Even when I manually create the folder `proj_root/figures/`, plots are not output to here.

#### What I've tried

- I tried setting the chunk options for a single chunk that outputs a plot to `fig.path = "figures/"`, which does not produce anything
- In a setup chunk, I've run these lines:

```
# load knitr package
library(knitr)
# set all subsequent chunks' working dir as the project root dir
opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
# set this first setup chunk working dir to project root dir (since the previous line does not affect the chunk it's run in)
setwd(rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
# Check current working dir
getwd() # CORRECTLY OUTPUTS R.PROJECT ROOT DIR

# Set all chunks to output plots to the dir "figures/"
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "figures/") # This should output all chunk plots to "project-root/figures/"
```

, which I assume should make the `project-root/figures/` folder and output all chunk plots there, in addition to keeping them in the .nb.html report.

I've also tried also specifying `dev = "pdf"` in the global chunks option in `opts_chunk$set(dev = "pdf", fig.path = "figures/")`, but this doesn't change anything.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and everywhere I've searched, none of the options work, including:

- [Knitr with R Markdown](https://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html)
- [knitr Documentation: Options: Plots](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots)
- [knitr: include figures in report *and* output figures to separate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992239/knitr-include-figures-in-report-and-output-figures-to-separate-files)
- [change where rmarkdown saves images generated by r code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083106/change-where-rmarkdown-saves-images-generated-by-r-code)

The [knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots) is unhelpful as it only describes the `fig.path =` chunk option, but no troubleshooting if it doesn't work. Do I need to add other `fig.*** =` chunk options in order to make it work? Shouldn't it work with only setting the `fig.path =` option?

Does it have anything to do with my YAML output being `html_notebook` instead of outputting to markdown or `html_document`?

The closest post to my problem I have come across is this one: [R Notebook: Include figures in report and save plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435594/r-notebook-include-figures-in-report-and-save-plots), but it has not been resolved since 2018 and I'm not sure how to 'promote' that post other than making a new one and referencing it.

Comment: You can save plots by explicitly calling functions such as `ggsave()`.

Comment: Yeah I know, and this is what I've been using as a workaround. But my issue is with the knitr global chunk options not working as intended as that would be much easier to automatically save all plots than having to add several lines of code to every chunk, multiple if more than one plot.

Comment: Maybe you could `set self_contained: false` ? https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#document-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, but unfortunately I tried that as well. It did save a dir with a bunch of intermediate files, but the dir was in the dir of the .Rmd file (not where I want it) and more importantly did not contain any figures that I could find anywhere in the hierarchy... I will try to fiddle with that some more though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested and the fig.path option works as expected. please test the following rmd:

**Edit**: Make sure the output type is set to `output: html_document` in the Rmd YAML header, and also click `Knit to HTML` to activate the saving of the figures. This is separate from, and can be done after, running the Rmd document interactively or with `Run All`.
See comments below

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "TC"
date: "10/30/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.path="testit/")
```

## R Markdown

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600399/how-do-you-run-an-r-file-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment103544013_58600399

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```


```{r echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[rmd source](https://github.com/tcgriffith/cosx_exps/blob/master/test106.Rmd)

and [here is the generated figures under testit](https://github.com/tcgriffith/cosx_exps/tree/master/testit)

Comment: Still didn't work... I completely quit RStudio, opened it up fresh (i.e. no previous Rproject), made a new R Notebook script, saved it to a new folder on my desktop called `test-Rmd`, copy/pasted your source code to the document, clicked `Run All`, and there is no `testit/` folder inside the folder the script was run from. Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: Try to click the knit button, not `run all`.

Comment: That worked! It seems the issue is that I had `output: html_notebook` in my YAML front matter whereas you had `output: html_document`. Can you update your answer accordingly? While this does work in saving all the figures, I have to manually press `Knit to HTML` -- it doesn't seem I can stay in notebook format while getting this to work. I might open an issue about this. I would prefer to have this work while being able to stay in R Notebook format as I like to use the `Preview [Notebook]` option.

Comment: Notebook is actually rmarkdown under the hood. So you could freely jump between html_document and html_notebook if you like.

Comment: Yes I know, but `fig.path=` output simply doesn't work when the YAML output option is set to `output: html_notebook`. There's clearly something different about how knitr processes an R Notebook vs. R Markdown with regards to that option. I would prefer to just be able to leave it as `output: html_notebook`.

Comment: Hi,@leo By inspecting the images in chrome devtools(F12), it seems that all images are stored in the html in the form of  base64 string, even I specified self_contained as false. So I think the "no png output for notebook" is a design choice (maybe I'm wrong).