# How do you run an R file on ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I tried to run an Rscript file from my ubuntu terminal on the server using the code:

```
Rscript etl/ConceptTables/loadTables.R mimiciii"
```

The file is located in stated directory below but I need to run the script from the root directory. However, it is saying this file does not exist but it clearly does. I also tried running this by entering the R environment first but instead, I get:

```
"Error: Unexpected symbol in "etl/ConceptTables/loadTables.R mimiciii"
```

I am following instructions from this mimic-omoop ETL on github here: https://github.com/chichukw/mimic-omop/blob/master/README-run-etl.md and I already created the cpg file with my username and database name. Could anyone clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use the full path of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full path of the file. The error you have posted is "Unexpected symbol"

Could be because you have added a double quote at the end of mimiciii. Or is it a mistake while posting the question?

If you are using double quotes for the path, ensure that it is " and not “.

Comment: The "unexpected symbol" error is because OP is trying to run a system command at the R terminal. You'd get the same error typing `blah blah` for instance.